# Java stream sum of gaps

Tags: java, stream

A little context: I'm trying detect barcode scanner signals (this model presses enter after printing the scanned value) by taking the average difference between key input instants.

Recently i've been looking at Subramanian talks about Java 8 and so, i don't understand how to translate this loop into a stream.

```
List<Instant> instants = new ArrayList<>();

content.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, e->{
        switch (e.getCode()) {
            case ENTER:
                int sum = 1;//sum starts at one to prevent division by zero failure
                for(int i = 1 ; i < instants.size(); i++) {
                    sum+=ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(instants.get(i), instants.get(i-1));
                }
                System.out.println(sum/instants.size());
                //average barcode is 3 or 4
                //my best try was about 90, it's pretty safe...i guess
                instants.clear();
                break;
            default:
                instants.add(Instant.now());
                break;
        }
    });
```

Comment: You can't translate that loop into a stream, because a stream processes values independently, so you cannot compare adjacent values. I guess you *could* write your own `Collector` to do this, but what would be the point?

Comment: Lets say you have 5 `Instant` values. Lets call them `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`. Now you sum the differences: `sum = (B-A) + (C-B) + (D-C) + (E-D)`. Hmmm, that all adds up to `sum = E - A`. All the intermediate values null out each other. No need to stream or loop at all, just subtract last value from first, and you're done.

Comment: Why do you believe that you need to start `sum` at `1` to prevent division by zero? You're not dividing by `sum` anywhere. You are dividing by `instants.size()`, which can be zero, e.g. if user presses ENTER twice in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop or a stream, because the sum of the differences is the same as the difference between the first and last.

You only need this one-liner:

```
int sum = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(instants.get(0), instants.get(instants.size() -1));
```